# How to change Port Number Of Http Server in either Oracle10g or tomcat?

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, oracle10g

I am looking to run Apache tomcat and oracle10g... both are on port 8080 how to change port of any of them?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, probably better suited to [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you're running two listeners on 8080?

In Oracle's embedded gateway, from sqlplus:

```
exec dbms_xdb.sethttpport(80);
alter system register;
```

For Tomcat, see: http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-change-tomcat-default-port/

Answer (score 0):

Oracle XMLDB uses the ports 2100/8080 by default. Sometimes there are problem with other webservers (e.g. JBOSS) running on the same port.

Even if the package `dbms_xdb` is granted to PUBLIC you need DBA privileges to change the ports.

*-- change HTTP port from 8080 to 8083--->*

```
sql>call dbms_xdb.cfg_update(updateXML(dbms_xdb.cfg_get(), '/xdbconfig/sysconfig /protocolconfig/httpconfig/http-port/text()', 8083));
```

*-- change FTP port from 2100 to 2111---->*

```
sql>call dbms_xdb.cfg_update(updateXML( dbms_xdb.cfg_get(), '/xdbconfig/sysconfig/protocolconfig/ftpconfig/ftp-port/text()' , 2111));
```

*-- refresh settings---->*

```
sql>exec dbms_xdb.cfg_refresh;
```